# Implementing smartLifeCycle with a reactor subscription

Tags: spring, kotlin, project-reactor

Below is code I have for a component that starts a `Flux` and subscribes to it, all within the constructor of the class. This particular flux comes from a mongoChangeStreams call. It does not terminate unless there is an error.

I want the subscription to stay alive constantly so I restart the subscription in the event in terminates due to an error.

It has occurred to me that calling subscribe within a constructor might be a bad idea. Also I should probably enable a way to shut down this app gracefully by calling cancel on the subscription during shutdown.

My guess is that I should be implementing `SmartLifeCycle` but I'm not sure how to do that. Is there a standard way of implementing SmartLifeCycle on a component backed by a Flux subscription?

```
@Component
class SubscriptionManager(
    private val fooFluxProvider: FooFluxProvider, //calling foos() on this returns a Flux of foos
    private val fooProcessor: FooProcessor
)  {

    private var subscription: BaseSubscriber<Foo> = subscribe() //called in constructor

    private fun subscribe() = buildSubscriber().also {
        fooFluxProvider.foos().subscribe(it)
    }

    private fun buildSubscriber(): BaseSubscriber<Foo> {
        return object : BaseSubscriber<Foo>() {
            override fun hookOnSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {

                subscription.request(1)
            }

            override fun hookOnNext(value: Foo) {
                //process the foo
                fooProcessor.process(value)//sync call
                //ask for another foo
                request(1)
            }

            override fun hookOnError(throwable: Throwable) {
                logger.error("Something went wrong, restarting subscription", throwable)
                //restart the subscription. We'll recover if we're lucky
               subscription = subscribe()
            }
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of creating a Subscriber subclass that resubscribes on exception, chain one of the `retry*` operators on the Flux before subscribing.  The retry operators will resubscribe to the upstream Flux if it completes with an exception.  For example, `fooFluxProvider.foos().retry()` will retry indefinitely.  There are other variations of `retry*` for more advanced behavior, including an extremely customizable `retryWhen` that can be used with the `reactor.retry.Retry` class from `reactor-extra`.
2. Instead of passing a subscriber to `subscribe(subscriber)`, call one of the `subscribe` methods that returns a `Disposable`.  This gives you an object on which you can call `dispose()` later during shutdown to cancel the subscription.
3. To implement `SmartLifecycle`:

   - In the constructor (or in `start()`), create the `Flux` (but do not subscribe to it in the constructor)
   - In `start()`, call `flux.subscribe()` and save the returned `Disposable` to a member field.  The `start()` method is much better suited for starting background jobs than a constructor.  Consider also chaining `.subscribeOn(Scheduler)` before `.subscribe()` if you want this to run in the background (by default, the subscription occurs on the thread on which `subscribe` was called).
   - In `stop()`, call `disposable.dispose()`

Perhaps something like this:

```
class SubscriptionManager(
        fooFluxProvider: FooFluxProvider, //calling foos() on this returns a Flux of foos
        fooProcessor: FooProcessor
) : SmartLifecycle {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val fooFlux = fooFluxProvider.foos()
            // Subscribe on a parallel scheduler to run in the background
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            // Publish on a boundedElastic scheduler if fooProcessor.process blocks
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            // Use .doOnNext to send the foo to your processor
            // Alternatively use .flatMap/.concatMap/.flatMapSequential if the processor returns a Publisher
            // Alternatively use .map if the processor transforms the foo, and you need to operate on the returned value
            .doOnNext(fooProcessor::process)
            // Log if an exception occurred
            .doOnError{ e -> logger.error("Something went wrong, restarting subscription", e) }
            // Resubscribe if an exception occurred
            .retry()
            // Repeat if you want to resubscribe if the upstream flux ever completes successfully
            .repeat()

    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    @Synchronized
    override fun start() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            disposable = fooFlux.subscribe()
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun stop() {
        disposable?.dispose()
        disposable = null
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun isRunning(): Boolean {
        return disposable != null
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful and opened my eyes to threading issues I did not fully consider. 

Regarding point 2: The argument to the subscribe method is a BaseSubscriber which already implements Disposable